# PHP: Insert into a variable the database equivalent of the user´s chioce in a form selection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need PHP to take information from a form and compare it with a database information in this way:

***The user selects option X out of N options. Each option has a specific column in the database with a value stored in it. The value stored in the database assigned to the option chosen by the user is assigned to a variable.***

Here is what I´ve done:

This is my form option:

```
Cuál es tu color favorito?
<select name="colour">
<option name="redcolour">Rojo</option>
<option name="bluecolour">Azul</option>
</select>
```

I´ve created a variable for the option selected by the user:

```
$colour=$_POST['colour'];
```

So doing `echo $colour;` prints red or blue according the what the user has selected.

I have a mysql database with a table "datos" like this:

`datos (id, red, blue)` it has a single row whith these `values (1, 100, 200)`. Those values are the points assignated to each option.

**I need to have a variable $whatever with a value 100 if the user selected blue or 200 if the user selected red.**

If I do this:

```
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion,$query)
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
   if($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
      echo $result['red'];
      echo $result[$_POST['red']];
      }
```

I get 100 in the first echo, and get nothing in the second one.

My sql query is:

```
SELECT * from datos
```

Comment: don't you need `value-'XXX'` tag?

Comment: @jcho360 If you leave out `value`, it uses the text.

Comment: It´s not that weird really. I´m learning PHP and wanted to make an online test as an exercise, so people would choose some options and the script would rate them according to their results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM datos
```

Fetch the result row into an associative array, e.g. using MySQLI:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

or PDO:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then you can get the value you want with `$row[$_POST['colour']]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I´ve updated my question, because that solution didn´t worked. I´m using the function oriented way instead of OOP.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solved it using a switch:

```
  switch ($colour) {
     case 'redcolour':
        $colour=$result['red'];
        break;
     case 'bluecolour':
        $colour=$result['blue'];
        break;                              
     }
```

Posting it here just in case anyone needs it.

FYI, I coudn´t use `name="redcolour"` but `value="redcolour"` for options. "name" works only for the select.